# It's not that good "of an idea"

Tags: prepositions, american-english, colloquial-language

I sometimes hear some people saying,

1. it's not that good "of an idea" or
2. it's not that big "of a deal".

Is there a difference between above statements and statements below?

1. It's not a good idea.
2. It's not a big deal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If an idea is not good  then it is not good. But an idea can be good  but not *that* good of an idea. *That* here restricts how good something is, meaning it's not as good as someone claims it is, either now or previously.

I thought baking the chicken in coca cola would be a good idea. And it was a good idea, but just not *that* good of an idea (as originally thought).

So it was still a good idea but not as good as originally thought.

Sometimes we might say this as a step toward deciding or confessing that it was indeed not a good idea at all. Or someone who doesn't think  that it is a good idea might say it's not that good of an idea instead of just saying straight out that it's not a good idea. Anyway, sometimes we can't always be sure if our different opinion will be in line  with the final verdict.

The concepts apply for *deal*  and for a huge amount of nouns. Giving George a TV for Christmas was a good idea,  but it wasn't *that* good of an idea; it was more like a mediocre idea.